Shapely RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in XXX
I'm processing large amount of geo datas, but occasionally encountered some cases:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in distance
return lib.distance(a, b, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in shortest_line
return lib.shortest_line(a, b, **kwargs)

I tried them in python console and found that some specific data will cause this waring but the result is even correct.
Here is the code and an example data that will cause this problem.
What makes it more weird is that it will only raise the warning for the first time python tries to calculate this piece of geodata.
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon
>>> p = Point([444037.45235923684, 4432768.940062214])
>>> l = LineString([(444133.53324426746, 4432805.31270424),(444133.53324426746, 4432805.31270424),(444135.7614419243, 4432805.378952727),(444137.778475223, 4432805.432100361),(444139.7896194984, 4432805.446620431),(444141.81370974134, 4432805.440795805),(444143.84810851346, 4432805.423914926),(444145.8848029126, 4432805.401874071),(444147.92289024906, 4432805.380664571),(444149.96274860646, 4432805.363180846),(444152.0036369841, 4432805.350817922),(444154.0447198316, 4432805.344272887),(444156.08543010475, 4432805.343888665),(444158.1252506391, 4432805.349884151),(444160.1636512014, 4432805.362450611),(444162.2002235288, 4432805.381747374),(444164.23434018274, 4432805.408150714),(444166.2654926669, 4432805.442302018),(444168.292792287, 4432805.485611625),(444170.31557974376, 4432805.540908249),(444172.3342188634, 4432805.61411673),(444174.35935487103, 4432805.717899431)])
>>> d = p.distance(l)
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\shapely\measurement.py:74: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in distance
  return lib.distance(a, b, **kwargs)
>>> print(d)
102.73512328429545
>>> d = p.distance(l)
>>> d = p.distance(l)
>>> print(d)
102.73512328429545


These are warnings, not errors. You can just ignore them. Or suppress them, i.e. warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning, message="invalid value encountered in distance") and
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning, message="invalid value encountered in shortest_line").

Just found clues at the bottom of the page:
https://github.com/pygeos/pygeos/issues/167
That my LineString contains duplicate points.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
